# Finding a Named Range or Named Object

Tags: excel, vba

My Spreadsheet uses the `CHOOSE` formula to determine what table to use in a calculation.  I pre-made this choose formula with 12 names to choose from.  I haven't created all of 12 of the objects for this formula yet.

I tried naming a table after one of the names designated in the choose formula below:

`CHOOSE('Loss Template'!$M$50,Jun_20, July_20, Sept_20, Oct_20)`

NOTE: There is no known object with the name `Oct_20`

Excel said "the name already exists and I need to make the name unique."

Actions I have done:

1. I tried deleting the `Oct_20` from the choose and name the table then

   Same "Already Exists" Alert
2. Tried Finding the Object with that name using the quick access toolbar

   "Oct_20" Doesn't Exist and could not be found with that function
3. Deleted all unused names using VBA

   Same "Already Exists" Alert
4. Could not find `Oct_20` in "Formulas -> Names Manager"

I am trying to use `Oct_20` as table name any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: @BigBen Doesn't Exist there either

Comment: Can you name it ANY of the date strings?  Or is it only Oct_20 that causes a problem?

Comment: I can do other things like spelling out October entirely but I was trying to simplify naming by abbreviating but I cant with that month because "it already exists" despite me not being able to find it at all

Comment: I am just trying to delete what ever has that name currently so I can us that name

Comment: So you **CAN** name a table `Sep_20`?

Comment: oh it looks like I cannot name a table using the first 3 letters at all according to my sheet so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show **ALL** the names in your workbook, in a regular module of the workbook:

```
Sub showAllNames()
    Dim Nm As Name
    For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        Debug.Print Nm.Name, Nm.RefersTo
    Next Nm
End Sub
```

***Note:** If the `Name` doesn't exist, then the problem is that you entered the `CHOOSE` formula (containing the names) **before** you named the tables.  Change that formula to text; then try naming the tables; then change it back to a formula.*

Once you are satisfied that `Oct_20` is OK to delete:

```
Sub DeleteHiddenName()
    Dim sNM As String, Nm As Name
    sNM = InputBox("What Name?")
    
Set Nm = ThisWorkbook.Names(sNM)
  Nm.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Obviously, if for production, those macros would need error checking and other stuff. But this might get you started.

Comment: I get Run-time Error '1004' when I tried your above code

Comment: @PotterFan On what line?  And which code?  I posted two.

Comment: The delete code on `Set Nm = ThisWorkbook.Names(sNM)`

Comment: @PotterFan Did `Oct_20` show up when using the first code?  If so, what did it `ReferTo`?

Comment: @PotterFan You cannot delete a name that does not exist. Hence the error.

Comment: @PotterFan See my Edit

Comment: Thanks I will see if that helps.